# How to install FEATool on Octave (Ubuntu 18.04)?

Tags: octave

I want to install FEATool on Octave 4.2.2. Therefore, I went through these steps:

1. [Downloading](https://sourceforge.net/projects/multiphysics/) it.
2. Trying `pkg install FEATool-Multiphysic.tar.gz` in Octave command-line interface.

Octave returns this error:

> COPYING file missing.

Neither [GitHub](https://github.com/precise-simulation/featool-multiphysics) nor [FEATool](https://www.featool.com/doc/quickstart.html) provides any installation file for Octave or instructions about doing it.

Therefore, the question is:
How to install FEATool on Octave (Ubuntu 18.04)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a quick preliminary check, it seems that the FEATool **is no longer available or compatible with Octave** since FEATool v1.10.

While there was no explicit announcement for this either on their blog or changelogs, according to the main author of the software (as elicited below), this seems to relate to overhead involved in supporting Octave on top of Matlab. Furthermore, as the company seems to have effectively chosen (for their own good reasons, I'm sure) to intentionally follow a direction that explicitly breaks Octave functionality, it cannot be expected to work on this platform even as unsupported software. Therefore the answer to your question is that **"no you can no longer install this tool on octave (ubuntu or otherwise)"**.

Evidence that this software is no longer available for, or compatible with Octave:

- Mentions to Octave in the documentation from v1.8 have now disappeared and are exclusive to Matlab (with extra effort towards Matlab backwards compatibily)
- The .tar.gz package is no longer an Octave-compatible package.
- The main code relies on .p files, which obfuscate the code and are unsupported in Octave
- Past releases and source code have disappeared and are no longer available for download, both from sourceforge, official website, and github. Therefore it is not possible to download the octave-compatible v1.8 of the tool either.

Comment: I suggest trimming the second paragraph a little. Although I don't find it any offensive but it seems to have offended the developer as can be seen in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55981843/5698672). He may be having the right reasons to do so

Comment: Is there a copy/backup of "the other answer"?

Comment: @Tasos Thank you for your detailed analysis. The point that the old releases are not longer available indeed looks like the developer intentionally wants to break functionality for Octave users